# TensorFlow on M1 Pro Graph Execution Error

Tags: python, macos, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to use tensorflow with metal acceleration to train a model on my Mac (OS version 13.1), but I keep getting the following error when I call .fit():

```
2023-01-07 22:12:03.348930: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1830] OP_REQUIRES failed at xla_ops.cc:418 : NOT_FOUND: could not find registered platform with id: 0x131289e10
2023-01-07 22:12:03.348967: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1830] OP_REQUIRES failed at xla_ops.cc:418 : NOT_FOUND: could not find registered platform with id: 0x131289e10
2023-01-07 22:12:03.405602: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1830] OP_REQUIRES failed at xla_ops.cc:418 : NOT_FOUND: could not find registered platform with id: 0x131289e10
2023-01-07 22:12:03.405631: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1830] OP_REQUIRES failed at xla_ops.cc:418 : NOT_FOUND: could not find registered platform with id: 0x131289e10
2023-01-07 22:12:03.405654: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1830] OP_REQUIRES failed at xla_ops.cc:418 : NOT_FOUND: could not find registered platform with id: 0x131289e10

Detected at node 'StatefulPartitionedCall_7' defined at (most recent call last):
    File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/ml/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
      return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
    File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/ml/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
      exec(code, run_globals)
    File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/ml/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 17, in <module>
      app.launch_new_instance()
    File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/ml/lib/python3.10/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 1041, in launch_instance
      app.start()
    File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/ml/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 711, in start
      self.io_loop.start()
    File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/ml/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tornado/platform/asyncio.py", line 215, in start
      self.asyncio_loop.run_forever()
    File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/ml/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 603, in run_forever
      self._run_once()
    File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/ml/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1899, in _run_once
      handle._run()
    File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/ml/lib/python3.10/asyncio/events.py", line 80, in _run
...
    File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/ml/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/optimizers/optimizer_experimental/optimizer.py", line 1211, in apply_grad_to_update_var
      return self._update_step_xla(grad, var, id(self._var_key(var)))
Node: 'StatefulPartitionedCall_7'
could not find registered platform with id: 0x131289e10
     [[{{node StatefulPartitionedCall_7}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_5916]
```

Python: 3.10.8
TensorFlow: 2.11.0
TensorFlow Metal: 0.70

If I use the CPU for the training,`with tf.device('/CPU:0'):`, everything works fine.

I am using miniconda and have tried creating a new environment from scratch, but I still get the same error.

```
name: tf-metal
channels:
  - apple
  - conda-forge
dependencies:
  - python
  - pip
  - tensorflow-deps
  - ipykernel

  - pip:
    - tensorflow-macos
    - tensorflow-metal
```

I tried updating to the latest version of tensorflow-metal and all required dependencies, but the issue persists.

Any help in resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: This looks similar to out-of-memory errors I frequently get, and would explain why the CPU works fine—you're not just running out of GPU memory, right?

Comment: I attempted to change the batch size while keeping track of the RAM usage, but I couldn't identify anything unusual. Just to provide some context, I have 32 gb of unified memory available.

Answer (score 2):

> Python: 3.10.8 TensorFlow: 2.11.0 TensorFlow Metal: 0.70

you may want to checkout the reply of [this post](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/722873) where it suggests installing tensorflow-macos v2.10.0 and tensorflow-metal v0.6.0 instead.

This workaround works for me:

```
python3 -m pip uninstall tensorflow-macos
python3 -m pip uninstall tensorflow-metal
python3 -m pip install tensorflow-macos==2.10.0
python3 -m pip install tensorflow-metal==0.6.0
```

Comment: I tried downgrading and now everything works fine. Thank you very much!

Comment: It works. Thx.
Now minimum versions are:
python3 -m pip install tensorflow-macos==2.12.0
python3 -m pip install tensorflow-metal==0.8.0